# How to Patch On-premises devices from AWS SSM Patch manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ssm

I wanted to use aws SSM for Patch management for EC2 instances as well as our on-premises devices, like desktop, laptops, can someone guide me on how to achieve this,

I have created IAM Role for SSM and installed SSM agent on device and activated Onpermisses ssm activation, but my device not listing in SSM patch manager.

Answer (score 0):

To patch local, on-premises, services with SSM the SSM Manager needs to be installed on every server. This is done transparently on EC2, as many Amazon AMI include that manager already (if you spin you own AMI from non-AmazonLinuxes, then you also need to install SSM Client).

There is [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-managedinstances.html) (as always) for exactly this use case, see the especially the part for the manager [installation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/sysman-install-managed-linux.html). The guide provides a step by step manual on how to achieve your task.